# How to get the most recent commits in my GitHub repository to show in VS Code?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a GitHub repository with one other collaborator who recently made changes and submitted them to GitHub. However, when I open my project in Visual Studio Code these changes are not reflected in my project.

How do I download the most recent changes so they show up in VS Code and reflect his changes?

Comment: Is the synchronize button in vscode or in the github repo? @Christian

Comment: just type `git pull` in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can press the synchronize button in the lower left to run git pull and update your local repository. When the other collaborator pushed changes to a specific branch, such as main, make sure you have selected the correct branch.

In my example below, I have selected the main branch, see lower left.

In VS Code, you can access the synchronize button in the two places highlighted below or use the context menu + pull on the source control (`CTRL + Shift + G`) tab:

[image]

Learn more: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can update your local repository with pull, you can try this :

```
git pull <remote>
```